# Using MVC3 to create a view that Selects only a distinct record

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

So, here is the problem I have a database with over 100,000 records. I need to create a website using MVC 3 that will display the 4 important fields I need similar to the way excel does when using slicers or pivot tables so the old timers at my job will see the same format on the website that they are used to. The current tool is an excel pivot table that allows a user to expand or contract an area depending on the detail a user needs to see.

Right now the pivot table kinda looks like this

**Area**

+++ Program

+++++Sub-Program

+++++++++++Project

I am sorry if my drawing of the slider expansions are bad**

The database and coding systems I am using are MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2 and ASP.net with MVC 3. So what I need to do is starting with the Area find the distinct records that contain an area that has not been listed yet in and list them in descending order.

**example**

Area 1

Area 2

Area 3 
etc...

Then after finding all the distinct areas I need to display all the distinct programs, subprograms and Projects for each section. I am new to MVC and all I know how to do right now is use the html helper displayFor to display a list that includes every record in database.

Something like this ex.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AREA)
        </td>
```

I am just confused on how I should approach this problem, should I use lambda or SQL statements to narrow down the results or is their another way to get the desired result. Any advice or tutorials on ways to solve a problem like this would be appreciated as much as an answer to this question. I can post any code that would help, please just ask. Thank you for your time and help!

**Realistic Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DBFirstMVC.Models
{
    public partial class realistic
    {
        public string CAF_ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CC { get; set; }
        public string INVESTMENT_AREA { get; set; }
        public string MAJOR_PROGRAM { get; set; }
        public string DIVISION { get; set; }
        public string CLARITY_ID { get; set; }
        public string SPA { get; set; }
        public string PA { get; set; }
        public string PROJECT_NAME_ORIG { get; set; }
        public string PROJECT_NAME { get; set; }
        public string HIA { get; set; }
        public string HMP { get; set; }
        public string RESOURCE_MGR { get; set; }
        public string RESOURCE_TYPE { get; set; }
        public string RESOURCE { get; set; }
        public string PRIMARY_VENDOR { get; set; }
        public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CONFIDENCE_1Q { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CONFIDENCE_2Q { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CONFIDENCE_3Q { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CONFIDENCE_4Q { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ACCOUNTING_PERIOD { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> VALUE { get; set; }
        public int REALISTIC_PK { get; set; }
    }

}
```

**Index View**

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<DBFirstMVC.Models.realistic>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>

        <th>
            INVESTMENT AREA
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model.Distinct()) {
    <tr>
        <td>

            @Model.Select(c => c.INVESTMENT_AREA).Distinct()

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.REALISTIC_PK }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.REALISTIC_PK}) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.REALISTIC_PK })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```